# How to use Nginx Regex in the location

Tags: regex, nginx

I hate regex..

But in some cases I have to use regular expressions. How can I get the content in bold below?

https://proxyhost/**bucketname**/test/uid

```
location  ~* /regex/ {
    proxy_pass https://$1.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

I need use this regex to extract the bucket name and fill the real url in Nginx S3 proxy

Thanks!

Comment: What platform/language/application are you using?

Comment: Nginx, to extract the s3 bucketname to fill the real URL.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using python.

```
import re

url='https://hostname/bucketname/test/uid'

m = re.match(pattern="(?:https://)([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)", string=url)

m.group(1)  # returns 'hostname'
m.group(2)  # returns 'bucketname'
m.group(3)  # returns 'test'
m.group(4)  # returns 'uid'
```

Comment: Hey literally said he uses nginx.

Comment: @Marc
There was no mentioning of Nginx when I saw the original question. I'll delete this answer if that's what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
location  ~ ([^/]+) {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass https://$1.s3.amazonaws.com/;
    }
```

use "return 200 $1;" get the correct result, but now I get another error named
**SignatureDoesNotMatch**

researching...(google ing)

Comment: An answer should be just that; anything not part of the answer (such as the statement about another error) should not be included. Additionally, the solution could use an [explanation](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/90527) as to how it works.